# Google adsense and content security policy

Tags: javascript, adsense

I have developed a website, I want to add google adsense to the site.
I have created an adsense account and added the code snippet to my website. but the Google's addsbygoogle.js loads and writes some inline scripts and styles that the browser refuses to load because it violates my CSP rules.

[image: Browser log]

I have tried adding 'strict-dynamic' with a nonce to all of my scripts in the page, still it refuses to load these scripts.

It all works fine if I add "unsalfe-inline" but is there a more secure way to do this.

thanks

Comment: I've spent extensive time researching, hacking and  trying to have Adsense play along with a `strict-dynamic` (so by extention using SHAs and NONCEs) policy, but since their parent script attempts to create inline <script> tags with random content and from random sources, it's pretty much impossible. And you know what? Fuck 'em for that. They should have the whole thing in an iframe to begin with...